# for loop in play framework 1.2.5 (groovy template)

Tags: groovy, playframework-1.x

I am using the following code to use the for loop with a list (I am familiar with the other syntax copied below as well).  The first for loop is not working for me even though its the same list.  Any ideas on how to go about troubleshooting this:

```
#{list items:0..items.size(), as:'item'}${item}#{/list}  //Not Working - I have tried moving the items.size out of the loop as well but it has not worked for me
```

This is working for the same list:

```
#{list items, as:'item'}${item}#{/list}
```

Any thoughts/suggestions why?  Thanks in advance.

Edit: The list is that of user defined instances (primarily holding Strings and Integers)

Comment: for now, I'm using a for loop: for (int i = 0; i < itemSize; i++) - it works as expected

Comment: what's the problem with the second syntax ? can you explain what you want to achieve with the other one ?

Comment: I am now trying to figure out why I could not run the first syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is incorrect, the items parameter need an iterable and you give it an integer, if you need an index you can use the item_index variable